# Creating a view of multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I'm trying to create a view that takes a base table and joins it to information from multiple other tables and returns one row per row in the original table. For the sake of example, let's say I'm matching college graduates to employment and graduate school data... because that is, in fact, what I'm doing. Now, the issue here is that I can get multiple matches in the employment and graduate school data. People could work for more than one employer, or they could go to one grad school and then decide to transfer to another. This creates duplicate rows when I join, which then need to be eliminated through aggregation (or some other means).

My current solution is to do nested joins/queries something like this:

```
select ID, GradYear, max(Salary) as Salary, case when sum(case when S.Year=GradYear+1 then 1 else 0 end)>0 then 1 else 0 end
from
(
    select ID, GradYear, sum(case when W.Year=GradYear+1 then W.Wages else null end) as Salary
    from
    (
        select ID, GradYear
        from dbo.Students
        where Graduated=1
    ) as G
    left join dbo.Wages as W
    on G.ID=W.ID
) as Inner
left join dbo.GradSchool as S
on Inner.ID=S.ID
```

This seems a bit ugly to me, especially if I want to bring in more data (say, I now want to look for them in the military too). Is there a better way of accomplishing the joining? If I just straight up join the three tables together, I'll end up double counting people's wages if they have 2 grad school records, for example... Let me know if you've got a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  U.ID,
  U.GradYear,
  W.Salary,
  S.HasGradSchool
FROM dbo.Students U
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    SUM(Wages) AS Salary
  FROM dbo.Wages
  WHERE ID = U.ID
    AND Year = U.GradYear+1
) W
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1
    1 AS HasGradSchool 
  FROM dbo.GradSchool
  WHERE ID = U.ID
    AND Year = U.GradYear+1
) S
where U.Graduated=1
```